# Setting up maximum likelihood estimation with multi-response data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, modeling, nonlinear-regression, fitting, differential-equations

I was trying to fit the parameters of a time-dependent system coupled of ODES related to a kinetic experiment with multi response data.

Example:

A->B+H
A+H->C+H
A->D
dcA(t)/dt=-k1Ca(t)-k2Ca(t)*Ch(t)-k3*Ca(t)
dcB(t)/dt=k1Ca(t)
dcC(t)/dt=k2Ca(t)*Ch(t)
dcH(t)/dt=k1Ca(t)

I am measuring the data of A, B and C and I wanted to use the maximum likelihood (ML) approach for fitting the kinetics instead of the classical least squares approach to **obtain more reliable confidence intervals**.

All the data are single point measurement and we do not have any information about the shape of the error.

The measured quantities with time are correlated to each other and not independent.

- Could you help me please?

I have already parametrized for the solution with conventional nonlinear regression by adding the contribution of each measured variable. However, the C.I. on the parameter are still a bit large and can be improved by the ML approach which by the Bayesian theory should be much better.

This procedure is something the most advanced software for modelling have built in.

Comment: I think the book by Bates & Watts (Nonlinear Regression Analysis and its Applications) should put you in the right direction. You could use the compartmental model to get initial starting values.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to do ML without some information about the error.